# How to make star at the end of paragraph(which is of 3 lines) in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a star at the end of a para, but I am not able to get the appropriate result.

Html code:

```css
.A {
  display: flex;
}

.First-Para {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="First-Para">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus
  </div>
  <div>*</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the appropriate result?

Comment: I suppose wrapping the star in a span, and moving the span inside the div should do it. But I'm not sure that's what you want. Can you [edit] the question and explain exactly how you need the output to be?

Comment: @FrankerZ `Get 20% OFF!*` maybe?

Comment: You question does not seems to have enough details the convey the issue. Please add adequate details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need provide absolute to the star div as shown below.

```
 <div class="A">
      <div class="First-Para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus
      </div>
      <div class="star-class">*</div>
    </div>   


 .A {
      display: flex;
    }

    .First-Para {
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .star-class{
    position:absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<div class="A">
<div class="First-Para">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus <b style="color: red">*</b></p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

Use `vertical-align:sub;` property to set `*` `baseline` with text.

```css
.A{
display:flex;
}

.First-Para
{
font-size:40px;

}
```

```html
<div class="A">
<div class="First-Para">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus
 <span class="First-Para" style="vertical-align:sub;">*</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is what i get, what i want is the star should come next to "natus*"

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` and put this inside `First-Para`

```css
.First-Para
{
font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
<div class="First-Para">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus<span>*</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: taht what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to add the asterisk with a pseudo element like :after.

```css
.First-Para {
  font-size:40px;
}
.First-Para:after {
  content: "*";
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="First-Para">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look too good on the preview here due to the limited width, but on a site it should work well!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **superscript** and **star unicode** of the HTML

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus <sup>&starf;</sup>
```

it will look like this

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, natus <sup>★</sup>